# TikZ: How to rotate and then shift?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, rotating

I'm trying to rotate a node and *then* shift it along the X axis. If I do `[rotate=90, xshift=-20pt]`, the node will first *shift* and then rotate.

Comment: You need to change the order of the transformations. The first transformation applied is the last of the options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could nest the rotated object inside a shifted scope, i.e.

```
\begin{scope}[xshift=-20pt]
    \draw [rotate=90] ...;
\end{scope}
```

Answer (score 12):

The scope is not necessary. You have two solutions

1) with `cm={0,1,-1,0,(-20pt,0cm)}`

2) you can try to change the order of your transformations with `xshift=-20 pt,rotate=90`and not `rotate=90,xshift=-20 pt`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}   
 \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (1,1);   
 \draw[blue,->,cm={0,1,-1,0,(-20pt,0cm)}] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (1,1);   
 \draw[blue,->,xshift=-20 pt,rotate=90]  (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \draw[green,->,rotate=90,xshift=-20 pt] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, didn't know that the order had such an effect. Well, I'll remember that till next time.